# while using nested perl grep output differs. why?

Tags: regex, perl

kindly explain, why this issue comes
my **data file**

```
DATA----1
DATA----2
DATA----3
DATA----4
DATA----5
DATA----6
DATA----7
SAMPLE----1
SAMPLE----12
SAMPLE----13
SAMPLE----2
SAMPLE----3
SAMPLE----4
SAMPLE----5
OTHER----1
OTHER----2
OTHER----3
```

where I need entire line which start with **DATA** and **SAMPLE** to an array and an another array should have content which start with **SAMPLE** end with **two digit number**

I have got output with following script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH, "di.txt");
my @file = <FH>;
close(FH);
my @arr2 = grep { $_ =~ m/^SAMPLE.+\d\d$/g } @file;  ## this array prints
my @arr1 = grep { $_ =~ m/^DATA|^SAMPLE/g } @file;

print @arr1,"\n\t~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n",@arr2;
```

First writen as

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH, "di.txt");
my @file = <FH>;
close(FH);
my @arr1 = grep { $_ =~ m/^DATA|^SAMPLE/g } @file;   
my @arr2 = grep { $_ =~ m/^SAMPLE.+\d\d$/g } @file;  ## this doesn't print

print @arr1,"\n\t~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n",@arr2;
```

while run this one, prints only `@arr1` 
what would be the reason `@arr2` don't print

Comment: For me your both script is giving the same result. None of printing `@arr2`.

Comment: @Sant : Just remove the `$` after `\d`, you will get desire output keeping array in any order.

Comment: Always use 3 arguments to open a file with lexical filehandle and with error handling.  `open $fh, "<", "di.txt" or die "Unable to open : $!";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because of the behaviour of the global match `/g` option in scalar context

Every scalar variable has a marker that remembers where the most recent global match left off, and hence where the next one should start searching. It enables the use of the `\G` anchor in regex patterns, as well as `while` loops like this

```
my $s = 'aaabacad';

while ( $s =~ /a(.)/g ) {
  print "$1 ";
}
```

which prints

```
a b c d
```

In truth you're not interested in a *global* match in this case, you just want to discover whether OR NOT the pattern can be found in the string. The `grep` operator applies scalar context to its first parameter, so in using the `/g` option in this statement

```
my @arr1 = grep { $_ =~ m/^DATA|^SAMPLE/g } @file;
```

you have left every element of the `@file` with the marker set to right after `DATA` or `SAMPLE`. That means the next match on the same element `m/^SAMPLE.+\d\d$/g` will start looking from there and clearly can't even find the `^` anchor to the match fails

The [`pos` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html) gives you access to the marker, and you can fix your original code by resetting it to the start of the string after the first `grep` call. If you write this instead

```
my @arr1 = grep { $_ =~ m/^DATA|^SAMPLE/g } @file;
pos($_) = 0 for @file;
my @arr2 = grep { $_ =~ m/^SAMPLE.+\d\d$/g } @file;  ## this doesn't print
```

then the output will be what you expected

The correct fix, however, is to write what you mean anyway, which means you should remove the `/g` option from the pattern matches. This code also works fine, and it's also more concise, more readable, and far less fragile

```
my @arr1 = grep /^DATA|^SAMPLE/, @file;
my @arr2 = grep /^SAMPLE.+\d\d$/, @file;
```

Comment: Thanks @Borodin. delightful answer. I learned new implementation of `pos` function "pos($_)".

Comment: @Sant: Like many other built-in operators, the default parameter for `pos` is `$_` so just `pos`  is the same as `pos($_)`. But you can give it any scalar variable